# Send custom WooCommerce mail with user credentials after order with certain product

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to send a custom WooCommerce mail with user credentials after an order with certain product. To explain further: Someone buys a product

1. I have to check if the order contains a certain product id
2. I have to check if the customer is registered as a user already, if not it should create a user
3. Then it should send a custom mail with those credentials to the customer

I am struggling to get the following code to work. Especially I dont know how I can add my custom email-message with the credentials and a custom login link. Do you know a solution?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'check_order_product_id' );

function check_order_product_id( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    $order_email = $order->billing_email;
    
    //create custom mail
    function get_custom_email_html( $order, $heading = false, $mailer ) {
        $template = 'emails/my-custom-email-i-want-to-send.php';
        return wc_get_template_html( $template, array(
            'order'         => $order,
            'email_heading' => $heading,
            'sent_to_admin' => false,
            'plain_text'    => false,
            'email'         => $mailer
        ) );
    }
    // load the mailer class
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    //format the email
    $recipient = $order_email;
    $subject = __("Deine Login-Daten für Geomap", 'theme_name');
    $content = get_custom_email_html( $order, $subject, $mailer );
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    //send the email through wordpress
    $mailer->send( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers );
    
    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
       $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
       if ( $product_id === XYZ ) {
            //get the user email from the order and check if registered already
            function email_exists( $order_email ) {
                $user = get_user_by( 'email', $order_email );
                if ( $user ) {
                    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
                }
                else {
                // random password with 12 chars
                $random_password = wp_generate_password();
                // create new user with email as username & newly created pw
                $user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $random_password, $order_email );
                return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
              }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some strange steps in your code, comparing a product ID to XYZ to name just one. What I'm wondering here, if you want to create a user account right after an order, if that order contains a particular product ID. Why not use the built-in functionality in WooCommerce where users need to create an account before they can order? That way you can skip steps 2 and 3 and you only have to write code for step 1 that takes this into account (if cart contains a certain product ID, prevent checkout before an account is created)

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback. XYZ is just a placeholder. I need it exactly this way. I.e. it lows the conversionrate if you disable guest checkout. The product they can buy here needs a login to a special page on our site.

Answer (score 0):

Hey for the question "how I can add my custom email-message with the credentials and a custom login link",
In your code, there is this line

```
$template = 'emails/my-custom-email-i-want-to-send.php';
```

you could add the credentials there, you may pass other arguments as the second parameter of this function[wc_get_template_html](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_template/)
second, the code order will not work for what you are trying to achieve

in this line, you are sending the email

```
$mailer->send( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers );
```

And after that, there is a foreach loop for all the items in the order and creates a function looking if the user exists.

```
foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
       $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
       if ( $product_id === XYZ ) {
            //get the user email from the order and check if registered already
            function email_exists( $order_email ) {
```

This function is not been called.

I will suggest to take out that function from the foreach loop and call it inside if your goal is to check only if the product XYZ exists

and all of it before the email

```
    function check_order_product_id( $order_id ){
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $items = $order->get_items();
  $order_email = $order->billing_email;

  //create custom mail
  function get_custom_email_html( $order, $heading = false, $mailer ) {
    $template = 'emails/my-custom-email-i-want-to-send.php';
    return wc_get_template_html( $template, array(
        'order'         => $order,
        'email_heading' => $heading,
        'sent_to_admin' => false,
        'plain_text'    => false,
        'email'         => $mailer
    ) );
  }
  function send_custom_email($order_email, $order){
    // load the mailer class
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    //format the email
    $recipient = $order_email;
    $subject = __("Deine Login-Daten für Geomap", 'theme_name');
    $content = get_custom_email_html( $order, $subject, $mailer );
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    //send the email through wordpress
    $mailer->send( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers );
  }

  function email_exists( $order_email ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $order_email );
    if ( $user ) {
      send_custom_email($order_email, $order);
//not sure where this variable was comming from
      return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
    }
    else {

      // random password with 12 chars
      $random_password = wp_generate_password();
      // create new user with email as username & newly created pw
      $user_id = wp_create_user( $order_email, $random_password, $order_email );
//not sure where this variable was comming from
      return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
    }
  }



  foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
    if ( $product_id === XYZ ) {
      //get the user email from the order and check if registered already
      email_exists( $order_email );
    }
  }
}
```

Now as a conclusion, WP_user class doesn't give access to the password for security reasons, and they don't send it by email, you should not either is a very bad practice.

I will suggest you create the account and let WP send the default email and then you send another email with the link to your custom page, but not with the credentials.
That way they will receive two emails one secure and one with the special conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned low barrier to entry being very important...

I'd recommend linking to your thank you page and having the registration link there too. You can use SSO (Google/Amazon/etc.) options so that users don't need to register directly through WordPress.

I'm assuming the product ID has some kind of activation code? You can send that, encrypted, as a parameter to the registration page so that it's registered in their session. Once logged in, you have attached their activation code to the user account, and you're done.

Steps:

1. Customer buys
2. If they have an account: send them the link, and they're done.
3. If they don't:

   a. Send them an email with a link with the encrypted activation code.

   b. They will have to register (through SSO or through WordPress directly).

   c. Once registered, you attach their product to their user account, and redirect them to the page they care about.